# Google map api javascript get latitude and longitude?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

First of all, I was using the google map api to convert address to latitude and longitude. I can convert it and display it. However, I can't set the latitude and longitude to a hidden field so that I can use it to process...what did I done wrong?

I can get the alert

[image]

However...I cannot get the hidden field value which I set, it show...

[image]

Below is my code...

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function sayHello() {

        // get input address
        var address = document.getElementById('inputAddress').value;

        var latitude;
        var longitude;

        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

        geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {

            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

                latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();

        // find hidden field
        document.getElementById("myLatitudes").value = latitude;
        document.getElementById("myLongitudes").value = longitude;

                alert("ShopLatitudes: " + latitude + ", ShopLongitudes: " + longitude);


            }

            else
            {
                alert("Geocoder failed due to: " + status);
            }

        });


    }


</script>
```

Comment: What's the problem? Where are you calling that? What happens?

Comment: I can't get the latitude and longitude from the hidden field even after I set it...

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the hidden field asynchronously, after your form has already submitted.

You need to only submit the form after the async response arrives.

Comment: Could you please suggest how could I modify my code? Cause I am not good with javascript...

Answer (score 0):

The call to the Google API happens asynchronously. That means that the scripts continues while waiting for a reaction from the webservice. As soon as a response (the longitude/latitude) isreceived from the webservice, the callback function you pass as the second parameter of `geocode.geocode()` is called.

Because this takes a while, your script already assigned the (still undefined) longitude/latitude value to the hidden inputs.

To fix this, you should assign the longitude and latitude in the callback function that you pass to `geocoder.geocode()`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help =D I have try your suggestion. However the problem still remain...I updated my code on top

Comment: Could you add the code you use to get the value from your hidden fields? As this plunkr shows, the're actually filled correctly: http://plnkr.co/edit/aEMYpbLP1UHzpjdTUroB?p=preview

Comment: ya...you are right, but after I submit my form I cannot get the fill in data...I use Request.Form["myLatitudes"].ToString() in server side but no data get...

Comment: Are you sure your inputs are actually field by the time you send the form? You could check this by using your browser console/firebug or by temporarily turning your hidden input fields to visible text-fields.

Comment: ya...i also think that it set the value after the form have been submitted. Anyway, I have make use of another plugin which done this job more efficiently =D http://www.wimagguc.com/projects/jquery-latitude-longitude-picker-gmaps/